# What areas of the Raspberry Pi are useful to analyze with an oscilloscope?

Tags: power

I am already aware of the great usefulness of a logic analyzer to troubleshoot digital signal processing.  But what about an oscilloscope for the analog stuff?  Which, if any, components or junctions on the Pi would be useful to analyze on the scope to determine health or just to get a better grasp of how it works?

Comment: Probe all the things! :D (your question seems pretty broad. Do you have an issue in a certain area that you need to solve?)

Comment: Nothing specific.  Logic Analyzers seem to get all the attention.  Interested in what value-add we get from an o-scope.

Comment: Ok. Logic analyzers can be pretty cheap and you can even build them yourself - maybe that's why they're popular. I'm wondering which parts have analogue signals on the Pi... Maybe there are some comparators or op-amp circuits but it's probably hidden away in the processor. You could determine the threshold voltages for a logic high/low on GPIO and tell the rest of us what you found out hehe. Unfortunately though, I think the thresholds vary too much for practical use... Good question!

Comment: Analyze the serial pin. You could calculate the baudrate from the width of a bit.

Answer (score 4):

It's fantastic that you want to use an oscilloscope (scope) to look at the PI, they are fantastic tools for understanding circuits, and if you have access to one, then go for it!

It sounds to me that you are being vague because you have a PI, and a Scope, and are itching to use them both. If this it the case, good for you, but you need to be clear, on this forum, of what you are trying to achieve.

a) If it is the Pi you are trying to understand, then you'll need a [circuit diagram](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings), and a basic understanding of what each part does (look online).

If it's a mains connected scope, be careful where you place the ground probe (the one with a crocodile clip) as it's connected directly to EARTH, and you could potentially damage the PI, if say you connected it to a power rail.

b) If you want to play with the scope, then take on a [simple project](https://gist.github.com/boseji/7296435) and play around with the scope and software.

Good luck, you'll learn loads about circuits with a scope, so enjoy!

Comment: Good advice. Especially the GND issue is a major source of pain for the beginner...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was really stumped when my original question was downvoted because I thought it was a great question.  Since posting my original question I have given this more thought and decided to test the various circuits in the Pi for low-frequency voltage ripple under multiple loads to see how it propagates across the power buses.

Comment: The circuit diagram should give you the power/ground pin numbers of on the various integrated circuits on the pi.  Make sure you use a short earth cable on your probe,  to prevent pickup.  What sort of frequencys are you looking for?

Comment: Also test the ripple frequency from your power supply,  to make sure you know it's frequency.  Switch mode pow supply are sometimes very noisy!

Comment: I expect to find ~120Hz on the 5v bus since that comes from the AC Mains via the USB adapter.  On the 3v3 bus, I expect it to be in the 1.5mHz range since that ripple will be from the switching converter.  I'm waiting for some equipment to be delivered before I start testing.

Comment: Is it an EMC project you have?  I'm assuming the "m" in 1.5mHz is megga 1x10^6 not mili 1x10^-3.  That's quite high for a common switch mode psu (SMPSU) switching frequency,  unless it's a harmonic of the switching frequency.  Before you jump in with the scope,  I'd load the SMPSU with a passive load to check what's coming from it. I'd also check the clock frequency of the pi, thereby you'll be sure what's from the pi and what's from the SMPSU.

Comment: @reggie, you are quite correct to point out my error in using proper upper/lower case on the frequency.  I need to be more careful about that!  I meant 1.5 MHz which is the frequency of the RT8020 buck converter used on the Pi B+.

Comment: You sound like you know what your doing,  so good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

When considering the best use of an oscilloscope, it's useful to classify the basic types of measurements and the most appropriate test instrument for each:

- Instantaneous readings for levels that remain mostly stable = Multimeter
- Waveform readings for digital signal processing = Logic Analyzer
- Waveform readings for analog signals that vary over a time domain = Oscilloscope

Power noise is a good example of an analog signal on the Pi that is best visualized with an oscilloscope.  I measured the noise on the 3.3V power rail and wrote about it in this [BLOG ARTICLE](http://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144555785379/exploring-the-33v-power-rail) along with a screenshot of the waveform.